# In React, how to test a render method inside a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, jestjs

I have a component which has a render method that is used to render a table. Now I need to implement a unit test in react to test that method (`renderTaskAssign()`)and see if the table was rendered successfully. Can anyone tell me how to do that? Here is the detail about the class that I hope I can write test.

```
class TaskAssign extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderTaskAssign = this.renderTaskAssign.bind(this);
  }

  renderTaskAssign() {
    if (this.props.data_loading) {
      return (
        <div className="dataloader">
        <ClipLoader
          color={types.LOADING_DATA_COLOR}
          loading={this.props.data_loading}
        />
        </div>);
    } else {
      if (this.props.current_tasks !== '') {
        const item_list = this.props.current_tasks.map((key, index) => {
          return (
              <TableRow key={index}>
              <TableRowColumn>{this.props.current_tasks[index]['pos']}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{this.props.current_tasks[index]['name']}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{this.props.current_tasks[index]['completion']}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{this.props.current_tasks[index]['current_task']}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{this.props.current_tasks[index]['percent_complete']}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{this.props.current_tasks[index]['status']}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>Do nothing</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
          );
          })
        return (
          <Table multiSelectable>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Pos</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Installer</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Work Progress</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Current Task</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>% Completion</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Add.Info</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
            <TableBody>
            {item_list}
            </TableBody>
            </Table>
          );
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderTaskAssign()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps=({ task })=> {
  const { current_tasks, error, data_loading } = task;
  return { current_tasks, error, data_loading };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TaskAssign);
```

I tried to use enzyme to test the component, here is the test code I wrote. I don't know how to test the table in my case

```
it("test renderTaskAssign method", () => {
    const renderer = new ShallowRenderer();
    renderer.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <TaskAssign />
    </Provider>);
    const result = renderer.getRenderOutput();
    const taskComponent = new result.type.WrappedComponent();
    taskComponent.props = {
      current_tasks: [
        0: {
          completion: 0.76,
          current_task: 'REASSEMBLE DOORS',
          name: 'A. Smith',
          percent_complete: 0.5,
          pos: 'A1',
          status: 'Good'
        },
        1: {
          completion: 0.66,
          current_task: 'ASEASSEMBLE DOORS',
          name: 'B. Smith',
          percent_complete: 0.7,
          pos: 'B1',
          status: 'Soso'
        }
      ]
    };
    taskComponent.renderTaskAssign()
    console.log(taskComponent.renderTaskAssign().type);
  }
);
```

Comment: @DavinTryon. Yes, I tried to use shallow render to render the component first. But I can't find the table, even if I passed data into its props already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you should test the behavior of your component, not its implementation. From the outside of your component, you should not care about if it has a `renderTaskAssign` or what this function does, but only what the component does/render.

What it seems you want to do is test your component with specific props, without waiting for your Redux connect to inject them into your component. I suggest the following, where you only test your component, not your store :

```
class TaskAssign extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderTaskAssign = this.renderTaskAssign.bind(this);
  }

  renderTaskAssign() {
      // some render code
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderTaskAssign()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps=({ task })=&gt; {
  const { current_tasks, error, data_loading } = task;
  return { current_tasks, error, data_loading };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TaskAssign);

export const TaskAssign // <- This enables you to test your component, without the mapStateToProps connection.
```

and then :

```
import { TaskAssign } from './'; // <-- Import the 'unconnected' version

it("test renderTaskAssign method", () => {
    const renderer = new ShallowRenderer();
    renderer.render( // <- Directly inject your props, not need for an entire store
    <TaskAssign current_tasks={[
        0: {
          completion: 0.76,
          current_task: 'REASSEMBLE DOORS',
          name: 'A. Smith',
          percent_complete: 0.5,
          pos: 'A1',
          status: 'Good'
        },
        1: {
          completion: 0.66,
          current_task: 'ASEASSEMBLE DOORS',
          name: 'B. Smith',
          percent_complete: 0.7,
          pos: 'B1',
          status: 'Soso'
        }
      ]} />
    );
    const result = renderer.getRenderOutput();

    // Test whatever you want : 
    expect(wrapper.is(Table)).toEqual(true);
    expect(wrapper.find(TableRowColumn).length).toEqual(7);
  }
);
```

Now, from there (and completely out of scope :-) ) :

- I do not get it what is the utility of your `renderTaskAssign` function
- It is recommanded to use functional components when possible (no lifecycle).
- You could replace your map with another component
- You can use babel-plugin-jsx-control-statements to simplify your JSX

So, I would actually write your component something like this :

```
const TaskAssign = ({ current_tasks, data_loading }) => (
  <div>
    <Choose>
      <When condition={data_loading} />
        <div className="dataloader">
          <ClipLoader
            color={types.LOADING_DATA_COLOR}
            loading={data_loading}
          />
          </div>
      </When>
      <When condition={current_tasks !== ''}>
        <Table multiSelectable>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Pos</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Installer</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Work Progress</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Current Task</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>% Completion</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Add.Info</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
            <TableBody>
              <For each="task" of={current_tasks} >
                <SomeItemTableRowComponent task={task} />
              </For>
            </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </When>
        </Choose>
      </div>
    );

const mapStateToProps=({ task })=&gt; {
  const { current_tasks, error, data_loading } = task;
  return { current_tasks, error, data_loading };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TaskAssign);

export const TaskAssign
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Basically, with **Enzyme** you can check if the inner component is rendered. For example:

```
it('should use Table', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <TaskAssign />
    );
    expect(wrapper.is(Table)).toBe(true);
  });
```

Then you can check that this component contains another component. For example:

```
it('should render multiple header columns', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <TaskAssign />
    );
    expect(wrapper.find(TableRowColumn).length).toBe(7);
  });
```

Comment: No, in my case I need to add values to the props, otherwise the table won't exist. So you case will never pass

Comment: You can add any props you want to <TaskAssign /> and renderTaskAssign will see it

Comment: No I used redux to do the work, so the table won't generate if I just pass a props to the component

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Jest** to generate snapshots. http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html

Comment: can you give me an example about it?